# Authorization and permissions in backend

Tags: appsec, authorization, openid

My Dev team creates high-load applications and wants to use Keycloak with OpenID authz. But they are complaining about delays for retrieving permissions from Authz server (Keycloak). So, they decided to define all permissions for each group/role in the backend. I guess it will be just hardcoded. This way makes permissions granting faster, they said.

What risks do you think may arise in such an implementation?

Comment: What does "in the backend" mean? There is not a lot of info here. Can you expand?

Comment: sure, by backend I mean a service which retrieve and process data from DB. There are clients with custom web UI which send requests to this service. Many people use this service to get classified and non-classified data. So, the admin decided to implement RBAC and use Keycloak. Developers hardcoded the roles and permissions into this service. I think it's a bad practice.

Comment: Why do you think it is bad practice? What risks do *you* see?

Comment: My concerns here that any user who can commit to git master branch can modify these permissions.  So, IdP doesn't work the way it should in this scheme. Moreover if some roles will be created in Keycloak later, we've got two points of access management. It seems not like a serious risk, but bad design

Comment: You have defeated the benefit of using OIDC tokens with database lookup. All attributes can be verified in memory. Don't solve a problem with a workaround, find out why the identity provider is producing delay.